# How to plot data on log-scale (y) in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, logging, yaxis

This question has been asked by others and I have tried to implement those suggestions, but to no avail.

I have log-transformed my data and want to make violin plots. I also want the data to be **plotted on a log-scale (on the y axis)**. I've been unable to successfully modify my code to get that to work. **There is a "NaN" in my data**, but I have no intention of playing with the data itself, *only changing the axis on which the data is plotted.*

```
#Making My Labels
cond = list('log_1' = "First", 'log_2' = "Second", 'log_3' = "Third", 'log_4' = "Fourth")
cond_labeller = function(variable,value){
  return(cond[value])
}


#Making My Graph
    MyData %>%
          gather(key = "key", value = "value", log_1, log_2, log_3, log_4, na.rm=TRUE) %>%
          ggplot(aes(x=Group2, y=value, colour=Age, fill=Age))+
          geom_violin() +
          geom_point() +
          facet_wrap("key", scales = "free", labeller=cond_labeller) +
          scale_x_discrete(labels=c("Placebo" = "None", "Control" = "Control"))
```

For Sample Data

```
MyData < - Age,Group,log_1,log_2,log_3,log_4
63,Placebo ,-3.657380787,-2.526854278,0.126606219,3.136275215
59,Placebo ,-6.074846156,-0.340970338,0.091651221,3.036528572
42,Placebo ,-4.456750181,-0.171904008,0.218709736,3.3370929
57,Placebo ,-3.215132839,0.015553416,0.285336825,3.358434755
64,Placebo ,-6.303439312,-1.363945957,0.435404097,3.056039198
57,Placebo ,-6.969630683,-0.440336095,0.22991259,3.067901296
47,Placebo ,-6.35963387,-4.474580616,0.357597518,3.142779354
60,Placebo ,-5.885304351,-0.592324947,0.293437975,3.121496265
42,Placebo ,-6.303439312,-0.844132874,0.091651221,3.036528572
62,Placebo ,-4.316238894,-2.292634762,0.360851211,NA
57,Placebo ,-6.969630683,-2.529109352,0.191751951,3.136471999
58,Control,-7.156216638,-2.491931265,0.16318121,3.240867427
54,Control,-8.111728083,-4.409603402,0.16120006,3.056852772
67,Control,-6.175387385,-2.76224243,0.162501429,3.043929405
49,Control,-6.214608098,-1.160721762,0.280574372,3.308625117
62,Control,-2.752276421,-4.474580616,0.168171921,3.177897985
47,Control,-6.110248083,-2.526854278,0.382332944,3.167377036
48,Control,-3.247532534,-0.944664487,0.091651221,3.093498072
50,Control,-2.752276421,-0.011728511,0.120330898,3.225446987
51,Control,-6.536191723,-3.758443917,0.275933325,3.287990982
45,Control,-7.024289095,-3.16937163,0.09932031,3.088100402
48,Control,-3.931205825,-3.031566727,0.15693537,3.099100356
47,Control,-2.752276421,-0.253886304,0.21257591,3.113649967
```

I have tried (unsuccessfully) to:

- Add "+ scale_y_log10()"
- Add "+ scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10")"
- Add "log = "y"" to aes(x=Group2, y=value, colour=Age, fill=Age)
- Add "log = "value" to aes(x=Group2, y=value, colour=Age, fill=Age)

These do not seem to work. The error generally seems to get upset that "NaNs" have been produced (I have one missing data point) - but I have no intention of changing my data. Only fixing the scale (by making it logarithmic).

Is there a way to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't log transform the data your self (as you have found when you then try to do this in ggplot you are log transforming it again which will be an issue due to the negative numbers)

Comment: One option would be to "un"log your `value` in your ggplot call, i.e. use `y = exp(value)` and use `scale_y_log10()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointing to the great suggestion of @stefan, here is the complete solution using `scale_y_continuous()`:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
MyData <- structure(list(Age = c(63L, 59L, 42L, 57L, 64L, 57L, 47L, 60L, 
42L, 62L, 57L, 58L, 54L, 67L, 49L, 62L, 47L, 48L, 50L, 51L, 45L, 
48L, 47L), Group = c("Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", 
"Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", 
"Placebo", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control"), log_1 = c(-3.657380787, -6.074846156, -4.456750181, 
-3.215132839, -6.303439312, -6.969630683, -6.35963387, -5.885304351, 
-6.303439312, -4.316238894, -6.969630683, -7.156216638, -8.111728083, 
-6.175387385, -6.214608098, -2.752276421, -6.110248083, -3.247532534, 
-2.752276421, -6.536191723, -7.024289095, -3.931205825, -2.752276421
), log_2 = c(-2.526854278, -0.340970338, -0.171904008, 0.015553416, 
-1.363945957, -0.440336095, -4.474580616, -0.592324947, -0.844132874, 
-2.292634762, -2.529109352, -2.491931265, -4.409603402, -2.76224243, 
-1.160721762, -4.474580616, -2.526854278, -0.944664487, -0.011728511, 
-3.758443917, -3.16937163, -3.031566727, -0.253886304), log_3 = c(0.126606219, 
0.091651221, 0.218709736, 0.285336825, 0.435404097, 0.22991259, 
0.357597518, 0.293437975, 0.091651221, 0.360851211, 0.191751951, 
0.16318121, 0.16120006, 0.162501429, 0.280574372, 0.168171921, 
0.382332944, 0.091651221, 0.120330898, 0.275933325, 0.09932031, 
0.15693537, 0.21257591), log_4 = c(3.136275215, 3.036528572, 
3.3370929, 3.358434755, 3.056039198, 3.067901296, 3.142779354, 
3.121496265, 3.036528572, NA, 3.136471999, 3.240867427, 3.056852772, 
3.043929405, 3.308625117, 3.177897985, 3.167377036, 3.093498072, 
3.225446987, 3.287990982, 3.088100402, 3.099100356, 3.113649967
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -23L))

#Code
#Making My Labels
cond = list('log_1' = "First", 'log_2' = "Second", 'log_3' = "Third", 'log_4' = "Fourth")
cond_labeller = function(variable,value){
  return(cond[value])
}
#Plot
MyData %>%
  gather(key = "key", value = "value", log_1, log_2, log_3, log_4, na.rm=TRUE) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Group, y=exp(value), colour=Age, fill=Age))+
  geom_violin() +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap("key", scales = "free", labeller=cond_labeller) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("Placebo" = "None", "Control" = "Control"))+
  scale_y_continuous(trans='log10',labels = scales::comma)
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: Hi there, this works great! Except that the bottom two graphs on this image seem to be on a linear scale for some reason, and I'm not sure why... Is there any way to ensure that all graphs are on a logarithmic scale? Thanks!

Comment: @Grace Yeah I have checked but looks fine. I don't know maybe is the nature of your data. I hope this answer helped you.

Comment: Yes it's helped very much! Thanks! One final thing - do you know how to get ggplot to add more tick/number values on the Y-Axis? Thanks

Comment: @Grace You could play with `scale_y_continuous(trans='log10',n.breaks = 10)` or other arguments like `limits`

Comment: Great thank you, used - `scale_y_continuous(trans='log10',breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(4))`

Comment: @Grace Amazing, you did it :) that is also valid!